# Tag sets - intersection

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags

How do tag sets work? I created one tag set containing "java" and "caching" and was expecting to get only question related to both of them. But it seems to return question related to any of them which is really useless given the number of matches. Is it possible to get the intersection somehow?

Comment: Two years later and something has changed. While I still can't see any use for the disjunctive tag sets, I have no idea how to create any tag set anymore. :D

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: tag sets do not currently support intersects (i.e. "java AND caching"), so vote this question up if you want that feature

Longer answer:

Tag sets are the union, not the intersect, of the tags you specify.  This is consistent with "interesting" and "ignored" tags on the Q&A sites themselves.  The idea is that you have a list of tags that you're interested in and want to follow.

I can see a use case for specifying intersects, but it would make the queries more expensive, and the UI more complicated (so I can enter `(java AND caching) OR c# OR asp.net`).  If enough people want it, we'll figure out how to add it.

Comment: I don't know how many Java question come each day, but surely way more then I could read. If I added anything to it, it could get only worse. Other may feel different, but I do not need neither union not complicated expressions, for me intersection is the only useful thing, at least for now. Instead of union, I can use multiple tag sets. Maybe a simple switch "match all of them"/"match any of them" in the UI could do. The queries would probably need to join more tables, but with users getting closer to what they want, they'd scroll less and so you'd get less queries.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I would love to have this feature.  I'm currently following the [interop] tag, but the majority of these questions deal with office interop, and I am only interested in the managed/unmanaged interop.  The intersection of [interop] with another tag like [c#] would be ideal.

Might as well add full set operations while you're at it! /partial-jest